# How many times has Uncle Ben died in the history of Spider-Man being on film and TV?

Tags: character, spider-man

With news [that Spider-Man and Marvel Studios](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/sony-fires-back-at-marvel-spider-man-movie-divorce-1233490) have parted ways (again?), it makes me wonder if there will be another Spider-Man reboot of some kind.

And if that is the case, will Uncle Ben die yet again in the series? And *that* makes me wonder how many times Uncle Ben has died in the history of Spider-Man being on film and TV.

### So how many times have viewers had to rewatch the death of Peter Parker’s Uncle Ben in the history of Spider-Man on the big and small screen?

Looking for answers that include animated films and TV shows as well as live-action films and TV shows.

[image: Uncle Ben dying in Sam Raimi’s “Spider-Man” (2002).]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Uncle Ben has died onscreen 9 times (so far).

Earliest death I can find is in [1967](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series)) animated TV show:

Second time in 1982 in [Spider-Man and His Amazing Friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_His_Amazing_Friends):

Then in 1994 during [Spider-Man (1994 TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)):

Then in the [Spider-Man Unlimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_Unlimited) intro from 1999:

Then in live-action Sam Raimi film trilogy where his death was shown in the [first film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2002_film)) from 2002:

…and then elaborated in the [third film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_3) in 2007 with Sandman involvement.

After that in [The Spectacular Spider-Man (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_(TV_series)) from 2008:

Then in live-action reboot film [The Amazing Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(2012_film)) from 2012:

And after that [Ultimate Spider-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man_(TV_series)) in 2012:

And latest in [2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2017_TV_series))'s animated show:

Comment: The death wasn't depicted in *Spider-Man: Into the SpiderVerse* but it introduced the theory of multiple universes, so many Uncle Ben's have died to bring us this information :)

Comment: Counting those up, that makes **nine** on-screen deaths. You may want to edit that into the top of your answer just for extra clarity.

Comment: Wow, thoroughly answered!